# Combinations of Asymptotic Time Complexities with Best, Average and Worst Case Inputs

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm confused by numerous claims that asymptotic notation has nothing to do with best-case, average-case and worst-case time complexity. If this is the case, then presumably the following combinations are all valid:

#### Time Complexity O(n)

1. Best case - upper bound for the best case input

For the best possible input, the number of basic operations carried out by this algorithm will never exceed some constant multiple of n.

2. Average case - upper bound for average case input

For an average input, the number of basic operations carried out by this algorithm will never exceed some constant multiple of n.

3. Worst case - upper bound for worst case input

For the worst possible input, the number of basic operations carried out by this algorithm will never exceed some constant multiple of n.

#### Time Complexity: Ө(n)

4. Best case - tight bound for the best case input

For the best possible input, the number of basic operations carried out by this algorithm will never exceed or be less than some constant multiple of n.

5. Average case - tight bound for average case input

For an average input, the number of basic operations carried out by this algorithm will never exceed or be less than some constant multiple of n.

6. Worst case - tight bound for worst case input

For the worst possible input, the number of basic operations carried out by this algorithm will never exceed or be less than some constant multiple of n.

#### Time Complexity: Ω(n)

7. Best case - lower bound for the best case input

For the best possible input, the number of basic operations carried out by this algorithm will never be less than some constant multiple of n.

8. Average case - lower bound for average case input

For an average input, the number of basic operations carried out by this algorithm will never be less than some constant multiple of n.

9. Worst case - lower bound for worst case input

For the worst possible input, the number of basic operations carried out by this algorithm will never be less than some constant multiple of n.

---

Which of the above make sense? Which are generally used in practice when assessing the efficiency of an algorithm in terms of time taken to execute as input grows? As far as I can tell, several of them are redundant and/or contradictory.

I'm really not seeing how the concepts of upper, tight and lower bounds have nothing to do with best, average and worst case inputs. This is one of those topics that the further I look into it, the more confused I become. I would be very grateful if someone could provide some clarity on the matter for me.

Comment: I think this question is better asked here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: All of them make sense. Which ones do you think they are redundant and/or contradictory, and why?

Comment: This question is answered [here on cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/how-do-o-and-%CE%A9-relate-to-worst-and-best-case).

Comment: @kaya3 For example, any of the ones where it is know that the input is best or worst case, shouldn't the bound be tight, as there is no ambiguity as to the range of "quality" of input? That would make 1), 3), 4), 6), 7) and 9) of no practical use, as far as I can tell from my limited perspective. Can you help me further to understand what I'm missing?

Comment: You would *always* prefer for a bound to be tight, in all circumstances, of course. But tighter bounds are generally harder to prove.

Comment: Oops, in my previous comment 4) and 6) should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

All of the statements make sense.

In practice, unless otherwise stated, we should be talking about the worst case input in all cases.

We're often concerned about the average case input, although the definition of "average case" gets a little dodgy.  It's usually better to talk about the "expected time", since that is a more precise mathematical definition that corresponds to what people usually mean by "average case".  People are unfortunately often sloppy here, and you'll often see complexity statements that refer to expected time instead of worst case time, but don't mention it.

We're rarely concerned about the best case input.

Unfortunately, it's also common to see people confusing the notions of best-vs-worst-case input vs upper-vs-lower bounds, especially on SO and other informal sites.

You can always go back to the definitions, as you have already done, to figure out what statements really mean.

"This algorithm runs in X(n<sup>2</sup>) time"  Means that given the function f(n) for the worst-case execution time vs problem size *in any environment*, that function will be in the set X(n<sup>2</sup>).

"This algorithm runs in X(n<sup>2</sup>) expected time"  Means that given the function f(n) for the mathematical expectation of execution time vs problem size *in any environment*, that function will be in the set X(n<sup>2</sup>).

Finally, note that *in any environment* actually only applies to specific computing models.  We usually assume a [random access machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine), so complexity statements are not valid for, e.g., Turing machine implementations.

Comment: I'm still struggling, as in my mind the concepts of "upper bound" and "worst-case" seem synonymous. I'm not seeing what an upper bound on average or best-case input actually means. I do get you point about average vs expected, which is helpful, but I'm still confused as to when I should use theta vs big-O in general when trying to figure out the time complexity of algorithms.

Comment: @RobinAndrews The best case input for problem size N is the problem of size N that can be solved most quickly.  For every size there is a best case problem, so there is a function f(n) that gives the best case time for each size.  There is a lot you can't know about this function without specifying the specific implementation, or maybe there's stuff about it that just can't figure out, but you can put asymptotic bounds on it -- upper and lower.

Comment: I guess what's confusing me is that if we know our input is best-case, for example, then why we need anything other than a tight bound, since there is no ambiguity about the input - it can't be better than it is in terms of how quickly the algorithm will execute on it. Does my confusion at least make sense?

Comment: The uncertainty in asymptotic notation is *not* about the input.  The uncertainty comes from not specifying a particular implementation/system, and not being able to prove all properties of the algorithm.

Comment: What you have written seems to imply that implementation details can account for an entire different class in terms of time complexity, thus justifying the use of an upper bound as opposed to a tight bound. Is this really the case, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Ah, no, I mean the reason we use asymptotic notation in the first place is that it erases the implementation details.  Upper bounds are used instead of tight bounds when you can't prove the lower bound, or you just didn't bother.  Proving the lower bound almost always requires a proof that is completely different from the upper bound.  The worst case lower bound statement is like "there exists at least one input that will cause this algorithm to take at least...", while the upper bound statement is "for all inputs, this algorithm takes at most...".